# Properly escape characters in input value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, escaping, character

My goal is to display `Sarah O'Connor` in an input as the value.  I need to escape `Sarah O&#39; Connor`  to show the correct UTF-8 html character.

I'v seen some answers that suggest replacing each individual special character.  But surely that's not the correct way as there could be hundreds of possible characters in peoples names from around the world.

I'v also tried javascripts `escape()` / `unescape()` and `encodeURI()` / `decodeURI()` functions, but they work only as html text not as input values.

Please see the jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gHHzA/

```
var div = $("#my-div");
var input = $("input");
var str = "Sarah O&#39;Connor";

div.html(str);   //--> Sarah O'Connor
input.val(str);  //--> Sarah O&#39;Connor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an element to put the HTML, then you can get the formatted result with `.text()`, eg:

```
input.val($("<div>", {html:"Sarah O&#39;Connor"}).text())
```